# Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)" Google Maps IOS

Tags: swift, xcode

Actually there is no error in the code. but when I run my app the google maps does not shown In the simulator and in the outputs area or debugging show me this sentence Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)

here is an image shown the simulator does have the google maps but it's not shown and when it's running it's show me this sentence Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)

[image]

This is the code :

import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate{

```
@IBOutlet weak var googleMap: GMSMapView!
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    }
    else{
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
}
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    googleMap.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0.0, longitude: locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude ?? 0.0), zoom: 8, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)
    
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0.0, longitude: locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude ?? 0.0)
    marker.title = "I'm here"
    marker.snippet = "I'm here"
    marker.map = googleMap
}
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print(error)
}
func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
    switch manager.authorizationStatus {
    case .authorizedAlways:
        return
    case .authorizedWhenInUse:
        return
    case .denied:
        return
    case .restricted:
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    case .notDetermined:
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    default:
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
}
```

}

Comment: In case you didn't know, each English sentence ends with the period, not the comma.

Comment: "The problem shown on the debugging area"  What is the problem and what is the thing that you so-call 'the debugging area'?

Comment: Why don't you want to explain what the problem is, 
what error you get, and where in your code?
It would be good to know what is the question you are asking? Also provide enough code to replicate your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for this question
The API Key for the GoogleMaps was not valid
Thats it
Simply I change the API Key

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).